# How to mock Tanstack library in Vue3 component test

Tags: testing, vuejs3, vitest, tanstack

I am writing test for a component that call an API with Tanstack

this my component

```js
<template>
  <span v-if="isPending">Loading...</span>
  <span v-else-if="isError">Error: {{ error?.message }}</span>
  <div  v-else-if="data">
    <AppTable v-bind:headers="tableHeaders" v-bind:items="data.results"  >
      <template #name="{ row }">
        <RouterLink v-bind:to="{ name: 'PokemonDetail', params: { name: row.name } }">
          {{ row.name }}
        </RouterLink>
      </template>
    </AppTable>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/vue-query'
import usePokemon from '../services/pokemon'
import AppTable from '../components/pages/AppTable.vue'

// init
const pokemon = usePokemon()

// states
const page = ref(1)
const { isPending, isFetching, isError, data, error } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['pokemons', page],
  queryFn: () => pokemon.getAll(page.value),
})
const tableHeaders=['name','url']

</script>
```

and I am trying to write some component test for that.

now I need to mock Tanstack

this my test code :

```js
// list.test.ts
import { shallowMount, flushPromises, vi, mockResolvedValue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import PokemonsList from './PokemonsList.vue'
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/vue-query'

vi.mock("useQuery", () => {
    return {
        default: vi.fn(),
        
    };
});

describe('http req', () => {
    let wrapper = null

    beforeEach(() => {
        const responseGet = {
            data:[
                { name: 'aa', url: 'url' },
                { name: 'bb', url: 'url bb' },
              ]
        }
        // Set the mock call to GET to return a successful GET response
        useQuery.mockResolvedValue(responseGet)

        // render the component
        wrapper = shallowMount(PokemonsList)
    })

})
```

But I get some error

*ReferenceError: Cannot access '**vi_import_0**' before initialization*

and I am unable to continue,

I need to know the right approach to test this component